# Instagram chatbot application is rejected on Facebook Developers Account

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, instagram, instagram-api, instagram-graph-api

I have created an Instagram chatbot application using [Messenger API for Instagram](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/instagram/)

As my application is a chatbot it does not require any kind of login for the app access but the review team is saying me to provide the login credential for the app. Now my question is that how can I give them credentials for an app which does not have any login feature.

According to [this](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/instagram/app-review/apps-for-your-own-business) documentation, I need to add a login URL for the app. But again the same question is how could I add the login URL as the app does not require any login for the test.

[Rejection reasons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XM4SS.png)

Please answer the question, so that I can resubmit the Instagram Chatbot application for the review process.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you follow all the instructions, on what exactly you should explain? Under `instagram_basic`, it says _"describe how your app generates access tokens (via Facebook Login or the Instagram Developer Dashboard)."_ - did you do that? If not, then it should probably not be a surprise, if they expect a "normal" implementation that provides a login to create the necessary tokens.

Comment: As I have created a facebook app there is no seperate Instagram Developer Dashboard. It is just showing Instagram Setting under the section. Currently I am using app access token to communicate with the app.

Comment: Not sure what exactly you'd be using an app access token for here, since using stuff like the Send API requires a page access token to begin with. But either way, just try and describe the actual situation as best as you can in your review instructions. If you don't need login to get any page tokens, then tell them so.

Comment: We have done according to your suggestion. Lets wait for the Facebook's reply.